# Call the same instance of jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a jQuery plugin below and would like to be able to call it again for the same instance on an element.

The plugin goes...

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function(options){

        var settings = {
            color: null
        };

        if (options) {  
            $.extend(settings, options);
        }

        return this.each(function(){
            var self = this;
            var pics = $('li', self);

            function refresh() {
                pics = $('li', self);
            };

            $('a', self).click(function(){
                pics.filter(':last').remove();
                alert(settings.color);
                refresh();
                return false;
            });
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

In the page this is called...

```
$('#test').myPlugin({ color: 'blue' });
```

Now I want to call the same plugin for the same instance but pass the string `refresh` as the option whilst all the other variables are the same (so color would still be `blue`) e.g...

```
$('#test').myPlugin('refresh');
```

This would then execute the `refresh()` function.

How could I achieve that with the above?

**Edit:** To make it clearer I am thinking of how jQuery UI does their plugins. In the [sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) plugin you can do `$("#sortable").sortable();` and then `$("#sortable").sortable('refresh');` on the same element. This is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: The click event should already have all the references it needs...does it not do work as-is?

Comment: Forget the click event, thats just an example of the plugin. I basically want to be able to call the refresh function on the same instance.

Comment: As suggested by Korvin, `.data()` is common practice, just make a closure of the jQuery Object and store it as a named data item on the Object. Bootstrap has [good examples](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html) for this.  
You could also store the using data instead of a whole closure, [html5sortable](https://github.com/farhadi/html5sortable/blob/master/jquery.sortable.js#L16) for example.
Furthermore, you could even store the value used to other places you control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your instance with [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) and check for it when creating an instance.

Something like:

```
$.fn.doStuff = function () {
  var ob = $(this);
  var data = ob.data();
  if (data.doStuff !== undefined) {
    return data.doStuff;
  }
  doStuff;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(function($) {
$.fn.myPlugin = function(options){
    var init = function($self, ops){
        $self.find("a").click(function(){
            pics.filter(':last').remove();
            alert(settings.color);
            refresh();
            return false;
        });
    };  

    this.refresh = function(){
       //your code here
    };

    return this.each(function(){
        var self = this;
        var pics = $('li', self);
        var settings = {
            color: null
        };    

        var ops = $.extend(true, settings, options);

        init($(this), ops);            

    });
}
})(jQuery);
```

try something like this. and you can call refresh() like $().myPlugin().refresh();